# Use reference voltage as power suppy

Tags: voltage-regulator, adc, voltage-reference

I am using MCP3202 which does not have Vref as independent input.  The datasheet states that the current consumption is:

```
550 μA max. active current at 5V
```

Can I use a voltage reference (Series) like LT1460 to power it?

LT1460 can provide upto 20mA as stated in the datasheet.

```
The reference will supply up to 20mA with excellent line regulation characteristics
```

Datasheets:

[LT1460](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1460fc.pdf)

[MCP3202 ADC](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21034D.pdf)

Comment: It is recommended to provide links to the datasheets in question.

Comment: Datasheets now attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this - you can even power low-power devices from Zener shunt regulators, which can supply far less current (and less stably) than the LT1460.

In fact, your LT1460 datasheet even says "The reference will supply up to 20mA with excellent line regulation characteristics, **making it ideal for precision regulator applications**" - which is exactly your application.